# Headings of different files do not match

Tags: include, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections, toctree

I have a very basic setup in Sphinx. The TOC is as follows:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3

   one
   two
```

And the files one and two look like this:

one.rst

```
####
Part
####

*******
Chapter
*******

Section
=======
```

two.rst:

```
***************
Another Chapter
***************

Another Section
===============
```

Both files have the same formatting and I would like to end up with the following structure

```
Part
|- Chapter
  |- Section
|- Another Chapter
  |- Another Section
```

However, Sphinx gives me

```
Part
|- Chapter
  |- Section
Another Chapter
|- Another Section
```

The reason I'm splitting the files is that they are fairly large and I want to keep them small so I can edit them easily. How can I get the same heading styles (with the same overline/underline characters) but in different files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is the [include directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include). For example in 1.rst you will put

```
####
Part
#### 

*******
Chapter
*******  

Section
=======

.. include:: 2.rst
.. include:: 3.rst
.. include:: 4.rst
```

This will include 2.rst and however many additional files you want in the current file and continue the current structure layout. Also, change your index.rst to be just the 1.rst.

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3

   1.rst
   part2.rst
   part3.rst
```

[image: example]